# Camel body is lost with 500 status when testing with ProducerTemplate

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a simple camel route:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/path")
.setBody(simple("<zzz>zzz</zzz>"))
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, simple("500"))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/xml"));
```

I have a test case with code like:

```
Exchange ex = producerTemplate.request("http://localhost:8080/path", (e) -> {
  e.getIn().setBody(requestBody);
  e.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
});
```

As soon as the response code is set to 500, then the body comes back as null. In fact ex.hasOut() is false.

When testing with curl the body is returned. So it's the test case use of producerTemplate that causes the problem.

What do I need to do to get the body I expect returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Http component translates 5xx status codes to `HttpOperationFailedException`.

You can turn this behavior off with option [`throwExceptionOnFailure=false`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html).

> Option to disable throwing the HttpOperationFailedException in case of failed responses from the remote server. This allows you to get all responses regardless of the HTTP status code.

```
Exchange ex = template.request("http://localhost:8080/path?throwExceptionOnFailure=false", (e) -> {
    e.getIn().setBody(requestBody);
    e.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
});
log.info(ex.getMessage().getBody());
```

Or obtain response body from `HttpOperationFailedException` object.

```
Exchange ex = template.request("http://localhost:8080/path", (e) -> {
    e.getIn().setBody(requestBody);
    e.getIn().setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
});
log.info(ex.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class).getResponseBody());
```

Comment: This is valid if you are using Apache Camel 3.x. If you are using Apache Camel 2.x, it is strongly suggested to use [http4 component](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html). `template.request("http4://localhost:8080/path?throwExceptionOnFailure=false",...`. And if you are using even older version, then you dont have `getMessage()` method, you can replace that with `getOut()`.